# Query string parameter with multiple values

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have this type of url https://www.ello.ie//requests/api.php?action=updateUser&query=1408998533,Mikal,name in this url you can see the query param who's value is some id, username,and filed_name.I am unable to make this type of url using alamofire. How can I set 3 values to one param
Here is my code

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["action": "updateUser", "query":[uid, name, type]]
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method: .get, parameters: parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.queryString).responseJSON { response in

}
```

Comment: What does it mean "I am unable to make this type of url"? What's not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["action": "updateUser",
                               "query": "\(uid),\(name),\(type)"]
```

Assuming all parameters `uid`, `name`, `type` are non-Optional.